# change the position of Masterview from left to right in Splitviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitviewdelegate

I have created on Split view controller which has master view on left side as default.Now I want that Masterview on rightside(as a Secondview) and detailview on leftside(As a first View)?
Is it possible if yes How can i do that?

-Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think if you use custom split-view then its possible i think so...
you can use some code of MGSplitViewController..
bellow is link of MGSplitViewController Demo...

https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController

you can get some idea from this Demo...
Hope this help you..
:)

Comment: I knw about this sample code but may be it's all custom it's not using any delegate mathod so to use that i have to change all the splitview controller

Comment: hey but here you can re-assign all delegate to your viewControllers then may be its work fine dude...

Comment: i mean give the parent view when any new view will push....hope this work and help you.. :)